# Выполнение программы в свёрнутом режиме

Tags: visual-basic

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой: 
 Необходимо, что бы программа выполнялась даже тогда, когда она не акивна(свёрнута) , выполнялась обработка нажатых клавиш функцией:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer) 
Label1.Caption = Label1 + Chr(KeyAscii)
```

Заранее благодарен...

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c4831) решение вашей проблемы. В хуках и win32Api. Смотрите, читайте, переводите.

Comment: А на русском никак? с английским у мя туговато...=(